# How to set " qml TableViewColumn " height?

Tags: qt, qml

I'am using Qml to develop a system, I want to change  `TableViewColumn`'s default height and its border style. I just want to show the bottom/right borders, to look like table.

Answer (score 0):

In your `TableView` you could define custom `itemDelegate` with borders and desired height https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-tableview.html#itemDelegate-prop

```
TableView {
    itemDelegate: Rectangle {
        height: 30 // put your height here
        border.color: "black"
        border.width: 1
        Text {
            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            color: styleData.textColor
            elide: styleData.elideMode
            text: styleData.value
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use rowDelagate property of TableView component.

```
TableView {
    id: idReadDataTableView
    anchors.fill: parent
    rowDelegate: Rectangle {
        width: parent.width
        height: 40
    }
}
```